# Joining 3 tables in Yii2 (error : Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have 3 tables in my DB:

`featured, news,event`

`News` is related to `featured` via `featuredOrder` and `event` is also related to `featured` via `featuredOrder`. The `featuredOrder` is unique, and I limited it to only 4 entry (1 to 4. It means only 4 selected items fron news or event will be featured). News and event did not relate directly. My application will display the news or event being featured according to their order given in `featuredOrder`.

This is my `news` model:

```
   public function getFeaturedOrder0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Featured::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

This is my `event` model :

```
    public function getFeaturedOrder0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Featured::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

This is my `featured` model :

```
  public function getEvents()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

This is my `featuredController`. I intended to display it via listview.

```
$featuredProvider=  new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query'=>featured::find()->JoinWith('news')->joinWith('events'),
            'pagination'=>
            [
                'pageSize'=>3
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'featuredProvider' => $featuredProvider,
            'featured'=>$featured,
        ]);
```

When I tried to echo `$model->news->title;` it works, but when I tried to 
echo `$model->events->title;`

It gives me this error : `Trying to get property of non-object`

in my `featured` table I have `featuredOrder` with 4 rows as value : `1,2,3, and 4`

In my `news` table, I have `1` featuredOrder value in one of my news, and in event's I have `2` 
 as featuredOrder value

I think it has something to do with my joining query, and the NULL condition while for example while the `event` table do not contain any matching `featuredOrder` value (or NULL). It's not a must to have a matching `featuredOrder` in both child table (event and news). I should have the freedom to choose which section to be featured.I used mysql.

This is how the relation should looks like:

[image]

I have been struggling for 2 days on this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATED :**  I looked more into the joins and decided to change my query and using `union` as it seems more suitable for my case.  My condition :
1. `news` and `event` do not relate to each other directly.
2. `news` related to `featured` via `featuredOrder`and `news.featuredOrder` may have NULL or may have matching value with `feature.featuredOrder`.
3. `event` related to `featured` via `featuredOrder`and `event.featuredOrder` may have NULL or may have matching value with `feature.featuredOrder`
4. The value of `featuredOrder` is unique, so `news.featuredOrder` would never match with `event.featuredOrder`.

This is my latest code :

```
$featuredNews=     featured::find()
    ->rightJoin('news','news.featuredOrder=featured.featuredOrder')
    ->where(['IS NOT','news.featuredOrder',null])
    ->orderBy('featuredOrder asc');
$featuredEvents =     featured::find()
    ->rightJoin('event','event.featuredOrder=featured.featuredOrder')
    ->where(['IS NOT','event.featuredOrder', null])
    ->orderBy('featuredOrder asc');
$query= $featuredNews->union($featuredEvents);
```

I found out that whatever I put first in my union query got recognized as an object (tested with `is_object()`. 
E.g : `$query= $featuredNews->union($featuredEvents)`; then `$model->news` is perceived an object while `$model->events` isn't. But when I changed it to : `$query= $featuredEvents->union($featuredNews)`; it's the other way around, `$model->events` is now an object and `$model->news` isn't

I tried running the query resulting from the union (without the select count *( and it runs well in my phpmyadmin. It retrieved data from both `news` and `event` that has the related `featuredOrder` in `featured`

`` (SELECT DISTINCT `featured`.* FROM `featured` INNER JOIN `event` ON event.featuredOrder=featured.featuredOrder) UNION ( SELECT DISTINCT `featured`.* FROM `featured` INNER JOIN `news` ON news.featuredOrder=featured.featuredOrder ORDER BY `featuredOrder` ) ``

I'm confused, what could probably cause this?

Comment: Everything looks fine. The next best step is to debug the query. Within the controller do something like this: var_dump(featured::find()->joinWith(“news”)->joinWith(“event”)->asArray()->all() );

Comment: Here is your problem: to handle the nulls you should do this: if(isset($model->events->title) { echo $model->events->title} else {echo “no match found”}

Comment: @DrBorrow thanks for your reply. I updated my query (in the end of my initial post) because I think using `union` is more suitable in my case. The problem is, one of the relation is not recognized as an object as I've added in my initial post. Still can't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `joinWith()` method by default uses `LEFT JOIN`. That means that your query will return all records from `featured` table and each record might or might not have related records in `news` or `event` table. When there is no related record then `$model->news` or `$model->record` will return `null`. If you try to access `$model->event->title` when `$model->event` is null it will cause the the error you've mentioned.

If you want to load all records from featured but want to avoid the error then you need to check if the featured record has related event record. For example by using `!empty($model->event)` or by using `isset($model->event)` as **DrBorrow** suggested in comments.

If you want to load only the featured records where the relations exist you have to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. You can use third param of `joinWith` method. Query like this will find records from featured where related news and event records both exist.

```php
featured::find()
    ->joinWith('news', true, 'INNER JOIN')
    ->joinWith('events', true, 'INNER JOIN');
```

If you want to select only featured records that have at least one of the related records you might need to combine `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` condition like this:

```php
featured::find()
    ->joinWith('news')
    ->joinWith('events')
    ->where([
        'or',
        ['not', ['news.title' => null]],
        ['not', ['events.title' => null]]
    ]);
```

You need to use where condition only when it is possible for record in `featured` table to exist with no related records in `news` and `event` table. If you are using query like that you still need to check the existence of related record with `!empty` or `isset` because there might be records that have only one of the related records.

You can find more info about joinWith in [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail). You can find the explanation of different join types [in this blog post](https://stevestedman.com/2015/03/mysql-join-types-poster/).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think leftjoin with where condition is what I need. I need to select featured record that have at least one (or even none if nothing is being featured) as you said it's possible for record in `featured` table to exist with no relation records in `news` and `event`

I tried to var_dump this but still got NULL :
```
var_dump(featured::find()
    ->joinWith('news')
    ->joinWith('events')
    ->where(['not',['news.featuredOrder' => null]])->andWhere(['not',['events.featuredOrder' => null]]) );
``` 

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Inner join is only used when I have  matching record in `all three` of my table, isn't it? The `news.featuredOrder` and `event.featuredOrder` won't have matching record because the `featuredOrder` value is unique. Though they would have matching `featuredOrder` with `featured.featuredOrder` though (or might have not if nothing is being featured)

Comment: @codejunkie sry, i've messed the where condition in that last case, it's fixed now. In your query if you var_dump it like that you are dumping the instance of `ActiveQuery` if you want to var_dump it's results you have to call some method that would execute it and return the result. For example add `->all()` to the end of that query. Also that query will work basically same as `INNER JOIN` because you are using `AND` so it will return only records where both relations are not null.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` will return those that have matching record in `all three` tables if you use it for both joins. You can use `INNER JOIN` in one relation and `LEFT JOIN` in other to get all records that have matching record in one table. For example if you use `INNER JOIN` for `news` and `LEFT JOIN` for events IT will return records that have matching news record even if they have no matching events. But it won't return records that have matching event record but no matching news. That's probably not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I looked more into the joins and I think using `union` is more suitable for my case, as `news` and `event` do not directly related to each other. The query returns data from both table but still I got the same error `tring to get property of non-object`. I've updated my query at the end of my initial post and have added additional information. Could you please check it? Thanks again.

Comment: @codejunkie changing the query won't resolve that error as long as the query is still loading some records that have only one of those relations. I'm assuming that featured will always belong only to either news or event, not to both of them at same time. Because of that when the featured record belong to news then `$model->event` will be null. When record belongs to event then `$model->news` will be null. That's ok, it's how it is supposed to work. You need to use `!empty` or `isset` check (as described in 2nd paragraph of my answer) to avoid accessing title of null and causing that error.

Comment: Is it possible to make `featured` can belong to both of them? Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just a beginner. I think `!empty` will works if in the record there's only a match in either `news` or `event` table, not both of them. In my case, `featured` could be either of these case :  no match at all to both table, only match to either news/event, or match to both news and event table. I got the said error even when there's a matching record in both table.